# Moving to c++: no rule to make target file.c needed by file.o

Tags: c++, c, makefile, automake

I've got a source base in C using autoconf/automake, which now should be compiled using a C++ Compiler.

So I've renamed all files from .c to .cpp and changed all makefiles accordingly. However I get the following error (e.g.):

```
make[3]: *** No rule to make target 'tmsConfigFiles.c', needed by 'tmsConfigFiles.o'.  Stop.
```

The Makefile basically consists of

```
bin_PROGRAMS = configparser

configparser_SOURCES = tmsConfigFiles.cpp tmsMoreFiles.cpp tmsEvenMoreFiles.cpp

AM_CXXFLAGS = -I .. -DSOME_DEFINE -Wall -Wextra -etc
```

This works for the overwhelming parts of the source code (some of which were cpp from start) but for some files the error message above appears. Did try to clean and autoreconf -is etc. to no avail.

The same revision works on Centos 6, fails sometimes on Centos 7, failes always on my Arch box.

Anyone had a similar bug in autotools or knows a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git clean -fx` did not remove .deps directories.

Removing them manually solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious thing that I can think of is that you have not re-executed `automake` (or more properly `autoreconf`) after changing `Makefile.am`, and for whatever reason (there are more than a few ways for that to happen) you don't have maintaner-mode enabled.

This is, though, assuming you are actually editing `Makefile.am` to begin with. If you actually edited `Makefile`, then it's the opposite problem, `automake` is doing the right thing and ignoring altogether your changes by re-generating the file that should not be edited.